# Integration of web.xml file in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, web.xml

I'm a junior Spring Boot developer and I have issues with integration of web.xml file in a project.

Is it possible to add that XML in my project without destroying my old configuration?

Comment: You don't need a `web.xml`. Unless you are on a very old servlet container.

Comment: Why do you want to integrate a web.xml file? What are your requirements?

Comment: i need this xml to do some configuration for external libreries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create directories `webapp/WEB-INF` in the `main` folder of your project and put web.xml file into `WEB-INF`. That should be enough for Spring-boot to take `web.xml` into account **BUT** as it was mention in the comment you **don't need to do that in 99.99999%** of situations of modern web application development.

If you add `spring-boot-starter-web` dependence into your maven or gradle configs you will have a fully configured TomCat web server inside your application and you can specify all options of it in `application.properties` file of your application of with some special classes.

Try to google about things I mention in this post and also came throug this tutorial of basic Spring boot web application https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: thank you fo the help, i know that in the most of modern webapp development is not necessary but i need for integrate an ejb configuration

Comment: Could you provide a bit more details about the integration you want to have? Do you plan to deploy a spring-boot application to some JavaEE application server as `war`?

Comment: i need to deploy my spring boot application on a weblogic server, and i need to deploy an ear that contain a war of my application and an ejb libreries

Comment: Ok. I guess you know that you can specify `war` as a target artifact in Spring boot initializer. And how I mentioned in my answer you can create in spring-boot application well known JavaEE folder structure to put there all server-specific configuration XMLs. If something going wrong, feel free to ask me here. I guess I can help.

Comment: i tried to use @ImportResource("classpath:web.xml") to import web xml but it give me an error like this: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [web.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Fine del file anticipata.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Fine del file anticipata. i

Comment: i tried to validate my xml, it seems to be correct. I dont understand where the problem is  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
</web-app>

Comment: I suppose for such kind of problem you should update this question or ask the new one. Very inconvenient to post big code snippets in comments.

Comment: i think i've found a solution to integrate web.xml in my project, at least i think that the problem was the version of xml header. thank you very much for the help that you give to me :D